# parsing a c file in bash(finding what's inside the main brackets)

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, sed, grep

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int max(int x, int y);
int main(){ 
    int a = 10, b = 20; 
    int m = max(a, b); 

    printf("m is %d", m); 
    return 0; 
} 
int max(int x, int y) { 
    if (x > y) 
      return x; 
    else
      return y; 
}
```

*i have this code and i want to parse to find just the main function like that:*

```
{ 
    int a = 10, b = 20; 
    int m = max(a, b); 

    printf("m is %d", m); 
    return 0; 
}
```

i tried with sed but i cant do this

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' esempio.c>main.c # to remove new lines 
sed 's/.*\s*main(.*)\s*\({\s*.*\s*}\)/\1/' main.c # parsing
```

Comment: Regular expressions parse regular langages. C is not a regular language; strictly speaking, it's not even a context-free language, when you take into account `typedef`s. Use a C parser to parse C code.

Comment: How much do you know about the formatting of the `main()` function?  How many of the variants of the first line do you need to handle?  Do you have to worry about K&R syntax?  How reliable is the formatting of the body of the main function?  Is the initial `{` on the same line as `main` or on a following line?  If you have only a minor subset of the syntax to deal with, an approximation with regexes is doable.  If you have to deal with any weird layout, then regexes won't work sensibly.  Do you have to worry about comments?  Strings?

Answer (score 0):

`cat a.c | awk '/{/ {m=/main/ }m' | awk -vRS='{|}' NR%2-1`

```
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    int m = max(a, b);

    printf("m is %d", m);
    return 0;
```

First `awk` extract main function.
Second `awk` extract code between `{..}` by using Record Separator `{ or }` and print even lines.

Comment: What if there's a bracketed block inside `main` ?

Comment: What if curly bracket gonna be used in `printf` ? ( `printf("}");` )  

It depends how deep you want to go inside that hole. Awk might help you with 
easy tasks. Simple `awk '/{|}/ {m=/main/ }m'` would be enough for the problem which was presented. But for more sophisticated stuff same parser need to be written which is used by compiler.